# Extracting data from an array of JSON objects for specific object values

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite-json1

In my table, there is a column of `JSON` type which contains an array of objects describing time offsets:

```
[
  {
    "type": "start"
    "time": 1.234
  },
  {
    "type": "end"
    "time": 50.403
  }
]
```

I know that I can extract these with `JSON_EACH()` and `JSON_EXTRACT()`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Items(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  timings JSON
);

INSERT INTO Items(timings) VALUES
  ('[{"type": "start", "time": 12.345}, {"type": "end", "time": 67.891}]'),
  ('[{"type": "start", "time": 24.56}, {"type": "end", "time": 78.901}]');

SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(Timings.value, '$.type'),
  JSON_EXTRACT(Timings.value, '$.time')
FROM
  Items,
  JSON_EACH(timings) AS  Timings;
```

This returns a table like:

```
start    12.345
end      67.891
start    24.56
end      78.901
```

What I really need though is to:

1. Find the timings of specific types.  (Find the first object in the array that matches a condition.)
2. Take this data and select it as a column with the rest of the table.

In other words, I'm looking for a table that looks like this:

```
id        start        end
-----------------------------
0         12.345       67.891
1         24.56        78.901
```

I'm hoping for some sort of query like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT(timings, '$.[type="start"].time'),
  JSON_EXTRACT(timings, '$.[type="end"].time')
FROM Items;
```

Is there some way to use path in the JSON functions to select what I need?  Or, some other way to pivot what I have in the first example to apply to the table?

Comment: Do the times always appear in the same order in the arrays?

Comment: @Shawn Unfortunately, no.  And, this is just a data sample... there may be 10s of objects in the array with a handful of other types.  There may also be situations where the specific object I'm looking for in the array may not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
WITH cte(id, json) AS
  (SELECT Items.id
        , json_group_object(json_extract(j.value, '$.type'), json_extract(j.value, '$.time'))
   FROM Items
   JOIN json_each(timings) AS j ON json_extract(j.value, '$.type') IN ('start', 'end')
   GROUP BY Items.id)
SELECT id
     , json_extract(json, '$.start') AS start
     , json_extract(json, '$.end') AS "end"
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

which gives

```
id          start       end
----------  ----------  ----------
1           12.345      67.891
2           24.56       78.901
```

Another one, that uses the window functions added in sqlite 3.25 and avoids creating intermediate JSON objects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.id
              , max(json_extract(j.value, '$.time'))
                 FILTER (WHERE json_extract(j.value, '$.type') = 'start') OVER ids AS start
              , max(json_extract(j.value, '$.time'))
                 FILTER (WHERE json_extract(j.value, '$.type') = 'end') OVER ids AS "end"
FROM Items
JOIN json_each(timings) AS j ON json_extract(j.value, '$.type') IN ('start', 'end')
WINDOW ids AS (PARTITION BY Items.id)
ORDER BY Items.id;
```

The key is using the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` to limit results to just the two objects in each array that you care about, and then merging those up to two rows for each `Items.id` into one with a couple of different approaches.

Comment: I have read several examples and I *still* don't understand what `json_each` is doing or how to use it.